# Waiting for Javascript function completion in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How to ensure that a Javascript function is finished before moving on to the next line in the HTML code.

For eg : I am having a Javascript code in `main()` and calling tht as shown below. Before this finish off, the next line of HTML code like loading a JPEG is showing up in the webbrowser. 
Is there any way I could ensure the `main()` call is executed completely.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> main();</script>
```

As some of you guessed correctly,There is an asynchroous call within the main() which uses a XMLHTTPRequest() to get some of the values I need to form the webpage. The function main is a s below

```
function main()
{
    var requestor = new net.Requestor("admin/getparam.cgi?mainvideostream&codectype", CurrentHandler);
}
```

and  net.Requestor=function(url,onload,onerror,method,params,contentType) 
  within this thers is and XMLHTTPRequest(...)

And the Currenthandler is another function which deals with the response from the requset.

```
 function CurrentHandler()
 {  
    settings = this.req.responseText.split("\n");      
    for(var j=0; j<settings.length-1; j++)  
    {
       var currentST= settings[j].split("=");    
       name = currentST[0];
       value = currentST[1];
       switch(name)    
       {
         case "mainvideostream":  cur_camid = value; break;
          case "codectype": stream = value; break;
        }    
     }   
    mainSection();
  }
```

So I have to find out the stream variable before loading the page.

Comment: I'm assuming the `main` function has some asynchronous code. Can you show the code that function?

Comment: am i right in thinking you want to delay the entire page loading until this bit of javascript has completed?

Comment: JavaScript runs asynchronously and the page loads asynchronously.  Even though there are some ways to block in JS (a very bad idea) you'd never be able to prevent the browser loading other things at the same time (nor would a user ever want a site to try and control that).  The question is: why do you want/need this functionality?

Comment: As Joseph noted, some more could would be helpful. One idea would be to set a flag that main() changes when it's done doing whatever you need it to do, and then check the state of the flag in order to proceed.

Comment: Sorry all tht I am not as prompt as you guys are. This is my first query here and I am really surprised to see such response . Thanks a lot again. @Joseph Yes the main function uses an asynchronous code.

Comment: @Jimmery Yes I want to delay the entirepage before this bit is finshed

Comment: @Rudu We are streaming JPEG or H264 files frm the camera. so I have load a quicktime object for H264 or a JPEG file based on the stream type the camera is configured to.

Comment: @j08691 I tried using wait on a wait_flag in main which will be activated at the end of mainsection(). this did the trick but it took around 12s to finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no (safe, standards compliant) way to stop the page from loading while your script runs.

Typically, this is worked-around in one of two ways:

1. Hide the elements on the page that you don't want to *appear to be* loaded by setting their CSS `display` property to `none`. Add a command at the end of your script to reset the display property on those elements.
2. Move the elements you do not want to initially load into a separate HTML file. At the end of your script execution, make an AJAX call back to the server to get that second file and load it into the appropriate point within your main file.

Answer (score 0):

If your code in main is not executed asynchronynously you should bind your code after DOM load event. Using jQuery:

```
$(document).load(function(){
main();

});
```

or without jquery, in your body tag:

```
<body onload="main()">
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, as the others here have noted the general order of things is to load the page then run javascript. however, you could use ajax to get around this. the basic idea would be something like this:

create a blank page with your javascript that runs when the blank page has loaded, and then at the end of this javascript code block, call in the page contents via ajax.

heres some jquery code that would do something similar:

```
<script>
$(document).load(function(){

//YOUR CODE HERE//

$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"", // <-- url of the contents of your page here
  dataType:"text",
  success:function(data){
    $(".container").html(data);
  },
  error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    $(".container").html("<pre>"+textStatus+"</pre><pre>"+errorThrown+"</pre>");
  }
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this without Ajax

Comment: sure, instead of bringing the page content in thru ajax, you could always get javascript to write out the page, like so:
`$(".container").html("_YOUR PAGE CONTENT HERE_");`
but id imagine ajax would be neater and easier to maintain in the long run.
any reason why you want to avoid ajax? do you want your code block to effect the page content that loads? because this could still be done in the success function.